Is it possible to change .NET MAUI Default fontsize
Is it possible to change the default font sizes of Title, Subtitle, Small, Micro, Medium, Large, Header, Default, Caption and Body according to user's preference?
I would like to set user's font size preference like:
Preferences.Set("Default", selectedFontSize);

And according to that I would like to change all the above default font sizes, say like Title would be 1.5x, subtitle = .8x and so on
Is the only way is to declare in global resource dictionary and use it like:
Application.Current.Resources["LargeFontSize"] = fontSize;
Application.Current.Resources["TitleFontSize"] = fontSize * 1.5;
Application.Current.Resources["SubtitleFontSize"] = fontSize * 1.2;
Application.Current.Resources["BodyFontSize"] = fontSize;

Thanks for your inputs and time

You need to read for "Dynamic resources".
